# How to get "open with" prompt for Custom tabs instead of always opens up in the default browser

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

[Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) always opens links in the default browser and beats the purpose of using it for SSO providers. My enterprise has a browser application that can provide sso functionality but when the other native applications open up the sso url in custom tabs it always opens up in the default browser. Is there a way to get the "open with" prompt when opening the custom tabs?

From Android 12 it is not even possible to clear the default browsers and one always has to be selected.

I am aware of the [bindCustomTabsService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsClient#bindCustomTabsService(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection)) functionality but it requires the package name to be hard coded, which does not makes sense to me since this is a third party app and it might use many idp's for many enterprises so hardcoding the package name for my enterprise is not practical.
Any guidance here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to break the problem into two parts:

1. Create an Activity or Fragment for choosing the browser.  The code in [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/#how-can-i-check-whether-the-android-device-has-a-browser-that-supports-custom-tab) shows how to list all compatible browsers. Return the package name of the browser chosen by the user.
2. Once you know the user chosen the browser and you have the package name, open the browser with something like:

```java
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(packageName);
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```